# VMware Player flooding my event log with information events about "I120: Service being interrogated...."

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player, event-log

Every few seconds a few entries of Information Event 1000 shows up in my event log saying vmauthd was the source. Here is the xml log of the event. all the others are identical other than a incrementing  and the timestamps.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="vmauthd" /> 
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
    <Level>4</Level> 
    <Task>0</Task> 
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-28T15:08:12.000000000Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>586380</EventRecordID> 
    <Channel>Application</Channel> 
    <Computer>src.redacted.com</Computer> 
    <Security /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>2011-11-28T09:08:12.777-06:00| vthread-3| I120: Service being interrogated....</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

It is quite annoying as in 10 minutes 64 events where put in yo my event log all saying the same thing. What can I do to stop this other than filtering event 1000 from vmauthd.

I am using VMware Player 4.0.1 build-528992, the host OS is Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1, This Information Event is happening when player is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible to "fix" this per [these instructions](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1987657)

> Delete or rename HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VMware

Answer (score 0):

You could also just stop the VMware Authorization Service, and the VMware Workstation Server service that depends on it, then set them to start up manually. Of course, this would depend on whether you actually need those features, but VMware Workstation seems to work fine locally without them.